# Sort with unequal whitespace in first column

Tags: linux, bash, sort

I need to sort this list by name, high temp and low temp:

```
Kuala Lumpur 78 56
Seoul 85 66
Karachi 95 75
Tokyo 85 60
Lahore 85 75
Manila 90 85
```

I figured since whitespace is the delimiter for a column I could just 
         `sort -k 1`
which gives me this:

```
Karachi         95 75
Kuala Lumpur    78 56
Lahore          85 75
Manila          90 85
Seoul           85 66
Tokyo           85 60
```

But the "Kuala Lumpur" is causing problems because of the space.

So I tried to treat "Lumpur" as a column and to sort the first set of nums I did

```
sort -k 3n
```

but I get this:

```
Tokyo           85 60
Seoul           85 66
Karachi         95 75
Lahore          85 75
Kuala Lumpur    78 56 <---Why is this out of order?
Manila          90 85
```

How do I deal with this one space?

Comment: How is the file generated? You should use a different separator.

Comment: the file was generated with cat. What different separator? I was thinking of using tr and removing the space

Comment: A comma `,` would be a decent separator here. I don't see how `cat` would generate this file. There is something behind, right?

Comment: Could you post the desired output? Sorting alphabetically seems to work in your example. The only problem seems to be sorting by temp, is that correct?

Comment: @terdon Correct. When the temp is sorted the "Kuala Lumpur" doesn't sort properly.

Comment: @Bernhard I didn't want to use a comma. I tried tabs after the names for the nums but didn't help much.

Comment: So changing the delimiter is an option? In that case, you should be fine. Just add a tab between the name and the numbers and between each temperature.

Comment: @terdon I'm having a problem with that. When I do sort -t'   '... and put a tab in with CTR-V then TAB I don't think its reading in the tab. I tried <TAB> as well

Comment: See my answer for how to use sort with tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have commented, it will make it easier to work with the data if it is comma separated values (CSV).

Here is my solution for converting the data to CSV:

```
$ cat file | sed 's/ \([0-9]\)/,\1/g' 
Kuala Lumpur,78,56
Seoul,85,66
Karachi,95,75
Tokyo,85,60
Lahore,85,75
Manila,90,85
```

It replaces any space preceding a digit with a comma. `\1` references the group ([0-9]), the digit after the space. From there you can use `sort` with the `-t` argument to specify a field separator.

```
$ cat file | sed 's/ \([0-9]\)/,\1/g' | sort -t, -k2  
Kuala Lumpur,78,56
Tokyo,85,60
Seoul,85,66
Lahore,85,75
Manila,90,85
Karachi,95,75
```

If you'd like to convert back to spaces or make a table, here are two examples:

```
$ cat test | sed 's/ \([0-9]\)/,\1/g' | sort -t, -k2 | tr , ' '
Kuala Lumpur 78 56
Tokyo 85 60
Seoul 85 66
Lahore 85 75
Manila 90 85
Karachi 95 75

$ cat test | sed 's/ \([0-9]\)/,\1/g' | sort -t, -k2 | column -s, -t 
Kuala Lumpur  78  56
Tokyo         85  60
Seoul         85  66
Lahore        85  75
Manila        90  85
Karachi       95  75
```

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '{print $NF,$0}' file.txt | sort -nr -k1 | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

- `$NF`: number of fields, `$0`: whole line
- `sort -nr`: numeric reverse (descending)
- `sort -k1`: sort by first column (delimited by sequences of spaces and tabs)
- `cut -d`: delimiter (defaults to tab)
- `cut -f2-`: fields 2 to last (doesn't collapse or strip delimiters)

```
ruby -e 'puts readlines.sort_by{|l|l.split[-1].to_i}.reverse' file.txt
```

- `readlines` = `ARGF.readlines`
- `split` splits on whitespace by default

Comment: I really like this solution. I was going to use `awk`, but not in such an elegant way. Thank you from 8.5 years in the future.

Answer (score 4):

If you can change your file to have tab separated columns, your life will be easier. If changing the file is not an option, this Perl one-liner will do it for you:

```
perl -ne 's/\s+/\t/g; s/([a-z])\s([a-z])/$1 $2/ig; s/\t$/\n/; print;' file |
  sort -t$'\t' -nk3
Kuala Lumpur    78  56  
Tokyo   85  60  
Seoul   85  66  
Karachi 95  75  
Lahore  85  75  
Manila  90  85
```

EXPLANATION:

- `s/\s+/\t/g` : change ALL spaces to TABs.
- `s/([a-z])\s([a-z])/$1 $2/ig` : change TABs that are between two letters (no numbers) back to single spaces.
- `s/\t$/\n/` : the first substitution introduces a TAB at the end of each line, change that back to a newline character (`\n`).
- `sort -t$'\t' -nk3` : use TAB as a delimiter (sort has a strange syntax there, I know, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1037487/1081936) for more information) and sort numerically on the third column.

Comment: I like that this answer addresses the OP without merely saying that if the OP had a different format, the problem would be easier. However, this did not work when I tried it with `/proc/filesystems`, but the answer from @Lri did. `/proc/filesystems` may be a special case because the first field is either present or missing, but it fits the pattern of trying to sort on a field that appears after a variable amount of whitespace characters. As an example mistake, the output has `<whitespace> btrfs` as the first entry, but `nodev autofs` is further down the list.

Comment: @chris that's a completely different situation since you have _empty_ fields, so `sort` cannot find a "second" field to sort on. You might want to ask a new question, but I think this should do what you probably want: `sed 's/^\t/XXX\t/' /proc/filesystems | sort -k2,2 | sed 's/XXX//'`.

Comment: Thanks, terdon. That's a fair criticism. However, I view them as the same class of problem, because "Kuala Lumpur" essentially has a field in it ("Lumpur") that the other rows do not. Also, thanks for the sed suggestion. I wound up using an answer based on @Lri's post. However, I like this one also. I'm going to keep both of them in my script for now (one in comments, both with attribution :) ) while I think about which one I like better for the general case of sorting based on a missing nth column. Yours may prove more straightforward for that.